# Create relationship table for one-row relationships?

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I have the following structure:

```
-- Table Users ---
-  User1
-  User2
-  User3

-- Table Roles ---
-  Role1
-  Role2
-  Role3
-  Role4
```

Every user has to have one row, not more or less. Should i create a new table, eg. `user_roles" and store the users role in there, like:

```
-- Table user_roles --
-  user_id = User1     role_id = Role2
-  user_id = User2     role_id = Role1
-  user_id = User3     role_id = Role4
```

Or, should I store the users role in the `Users` table? Since there will always only be one role for each user, I see no reason why not to keep it in the `Users` table. Am I thinking correctly or should it be in a separate table? Very simple question, but I've wondered for long. In the past I have kept the "key" in the `Users` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enforce that every use *has* to have exactly one role, you should add a role_id to the users table, make it `not null` and reference the roles table

```
create table roles 
(
  id integer primary key,
  role_name varchar(50) not null
);

create table users
(
   id integer not null primary key,
   username varchar(50) not null,
   role_id integer not null,
   ... other columns ...
);
alter table users 
   add constraint fk_users_rol 
   foreign key (role_id) references roles(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the specification will not change, you can store the RoleID in the user table. For the sake of expansion, in case you want to support more roles per user in future, you may have the UserRoles table. For now:

```
Users(UserID, UserName, ..... RoleID);
```

Comment: With a UserRoles table it will be next to impossible to force a user to have at least one role (which is the current requirement). If that changes, moving to a m:n relationship can easily be done later.

Comment: That's why I said for future sake. For now, RoleID in the Users table is OK.

Comment: Users will never be able to add more Roles, that will always be the same. I will however add a method of grouping users by adding users to "groups". Every user can be attached to multiple groups, etc. **Edit:** And for that, i will have a seperate "groups" table, and "user_groups" to attach them.

Comment: That's fine. I think the answer is the same, as long as the Role is not more than one, it's fine in the Users table. There is no point creating a separate table